# Fetch GeoJSON once and display on different styles on Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style

I want to add a province layer to Leaflet map, which fetched from 4 php for different UTM zones.

The corresponding sql table has **promotion** and **population** and **density** columns.

I want to fetch the GeoJSON layer once and display the provinces with different styles for each column values on Leaflet map with different names on legend.

then i have 1 multipolygon layer which i want to display in different styles for different column values.

Here is my full code for one case:

```
var ProvinceLayer = L.layerGroup();

// Fetch the GeoJSON data from multiple PHP files
Promise.all([
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone35.php').then(response => response.json()),
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone36.php').then(response => response.json()),
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone37.php').then(response => response.json()),
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone38.php').then(response => response.json())
]).then(data => {
    data.forEach(geojson => {
        L.geoJSON(geojson, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return {
                                weight: 2,
                                color: 'white',
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.9,
                                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.population_density),
                                interactive: true 
                };
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

                var popupContent = feature.properties.province ;
                layer.bindTooltip(popupContent, { sticky: true });
            }
        }).addTo(ProvinceLayer);
    });
});

ProvinceLayer.addTo(map);
control.addOverlay( ProvinceLayer, "layer1", {groupName : "Bölge Tipi"} );
```

I use this code 3 times to display in 3 different styles. Thus it affects the loading speed of web.

Have any suggesstion to solve in fact, fetched once and display in different styles on map?

Comment: In what way these three styles differ? On what data/parameters are differences based? Please edit your question and add some info about that. I also recommend getting a new keyboard where upper case button works :-)

Comment: i was mentioned, but now add as bold: promotion, population and density.

Comment: Do you want to have different `ProvinceLayer` layer for each style, or just show the same `ProvinceLayer` layer in different styles? Please edit your question and clarify this?

Comment: i add a simple description as well :) i have just want to display just one geojson with more than one style.

Answer (score 1):

Logic of your app is not completely clear from your question and code, so answer will be based on the following assumptions:

- only one overlay style can be displayed at once;
- when one style is selected, the other is removed.

Answer is based on data for official Leaflet choropleth example data (see https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). Implementation is done the following way:

- GeoJSON data is read only once and stored in `statesLayer` layer.
- `statesLayer` layer is styled using `stateStyle` function, where styling is dependent on global `styleSelection` variable.
- Selecting desired style to be shown is done through dummy `selectLayer` group layers which are not actually displayed on the map but are used just for setting the `styleSelection` variable and resetting `statesLayer` layer style to reflect selected style.
- `stateStyle` styling function returns style depending on `styleSelection` variable. For testing purposes it just multiplies `density` property by `styleSelection` value.

Here is the complete code:

```
var map = L.map("map", {zoomControl: false}).setView([41, -99], 5);

L.control.zoom({
    position: 'bottomright'
}).addTo(map);

var osm = L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
});

var googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
  maxZoom: 20,
  subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
});
googleStreets.addTo(map);

var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
  maxZoom: 20,
  subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
});
      
var selectLayer = [];

function getColor(d) {
  return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
      d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
      d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
      d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
      d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
      d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
      d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                 '#FFEDA0';
}

var styleSelection;
      
function stateStyle(feature) {
  var selValue, fillColor;
  
  fillColor = getColor(feature.properties.density * styleSelection);
  return {
    fillColor: fillColor,
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  };
}
     
var statesLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
  style: stateStyle
});

var baseMaps = {
  "OSM": osm,
  'Google Street': googleStreets,
  "Google Satellite": googleSat,
};

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

var url = '../data/us-states.txt';
fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    statesLayer.addData(json);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      selectLayer[i] = L.layerGroup();
      selectLayer[i].myId = i;
      layerControl.addOverlay(selectLayer[i], 'Overlay ' + i);
    }        
  });

map.on('overlayadd', function(evt) {
  var id = evt.layer.myId;
  if (styleSelection) {
    var forRemove = styleSelection;
    setTimeout(function () {
      map.removeLayer(selectLayer[forRemove]);
    }, 0);
  }
  styleSelection = id;
  statesLayer.setStyle(stateStyle);
  if (!map.hasLayer(statesLayer)) {
    map.addLayer(statesLayer);
  }
});

map.on('overlayremove', function(evt) {
  var id = overlayMaps[evt.name].myId;
  if (id == styleSelection) {
    map.removeLayer(statesLayer);
    styleSelection = null;
  }
});
```

That's how the result looks like for two different selections:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do is to create 3 different layers that are displaying the same geometries but are styled differently.

You could achieve that like this:

```
Promise.all(...).then(
  data.forEach(
    L.geoJSON(...
      fillColor: getColorForDensity(feature.properties.population_density)
    ).addTo(ProvinceLayer);

    L.geoJSON(...
      fillColor: getColorForPromition(feature.properties.promotion)
    ).addTo(ProvinceLayer);

    L.geoJSON(...
      fillColor: getColorForPopulation(feature.properties.population)
    ).addTo(ProvinceLayer);


  )
)
```

You add 3 layers after all the promises resolved.